# Why the expect test fails?

Tags: cypress

I have just started using cypress and I don't understand why this test fails. Using cy.log I get the current value (0) but in the next line I get this error: "expected '0' to be a number or a date".

```
cy.get('tbody>tr>td').eq(7).should('have.attr', 'value').should('exist').then(val => {
  cy.log(val);
  expect(`${val}`).to.be.at.least(5);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `parseInt` to convert string into a number.

```
cy.get('tbody>tr>td').eq(7).invoke('val').then((val) => {
    expect(parseInt(val)).to.be.at.least(5)
})
```